# How tow use an ArcGISCache layer along with an ArcGIS93Rest layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-rest-api

I want to have two layers in my OpenLayers map. The BaseLayer, as well as the overlay layer are being served by ArcGIS Server.

I have a problem with [ArcGIS93Rest](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/ArcGIS93Rest-js.html) when using [ArcGISCache](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/ArcGISCache-js.html) as basemap.

The problem is `ArcGIS93Rest` doesn't show up and there is no HTTP request to the service.

Is it possible to use `ArcGISCache` and `ArcGIS93Rest` together?

Here is the code :

```
var baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGISCache("AGSCache", "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer", {
    isBaseLayer: true,                     
    resolutions: resolutions,
    tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(layerInfo.tileInfo.cols, layerInfo.tileInfo.rows),
    tileOrigin: new OpenLayers.LonLat(layerInfo.tileInfo.origin.x, layerInfo.tileInfo.origin.y),
    maxExtent: layerMaxExtent,
    projection: 'EPSG:' + layerInfo.spatialReference.wkid
});
var forestLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest("ForestLayer", "http://192.168.1.36:6080/arcgis/rest/services/forest_editing/MapServer/export", {
    layers: "0,1,2",
    TRANSPARENT: true
});
```

Comment: Currently I'm having a hard time understanding what you are doing. IS your ArcGIS Map Service cached? What is the version of the ArcGIS Server? And why do you want to use both? If you tell us what you are trying to achieve, we'll be better placed to help you.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Okay. [One](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer) is ArcGIS Map Service cached and the [other](http://192.168.1.36:6080/arcgis/rest/services/forest_editing/MapServer/export) is dynamic Map.

Comment: I've been able to get both the layers to display, but there is still some problem, since the layer seem to jump around. Once I've a proper example, I'll post it here.

Comment: Just wanted to warn you, that I'm not sure why this weird behavior was happening; It is possible that my answer might be a hack, at best. If I were you, I would also post this to the OpenLayers mailing list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having problems redrawing the Dynamic map service on every pan & zoom.
So to solve this problem, I just called `layer.redraw(true);`

The important code is as follows:

```
function init(){
    //The max extent for spherical mercator
    var maxExtent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34);

    //Max extent from layerInfo above            
    var layerMaxExtent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
        layerInfo.fullExtent.xmin, 
        layerInfo.fullExtent.ymin, 
        layerInfo.fullExtent.xmax, 
        layerInfo.fullExtent.ymax  
    );

    var resolutions = [];
    for (var i=0; i<layerInfo.tileInfo.lods.length; i++) {
        resolutions.push(layerInfo.tileInfo.lods[i].resolution);
    }
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        maxExtent: maxExtent,
        StartBounds: layerMaxExtent,
        units: (layerInfo.units == "esriFeet") ? 'ft' : 'm',
        resolutions: resolutions,
        tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(256,256),                
        projection: mercator,
        displayProjection:geographic,
        eventListeners: { //set event handler
                "moveend": moveEvent}
    });

     cacheLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGISCache( "AGSCache",
            "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer", {
                isBaseLayer: true,

                //From layerInfo above                        
                resolutions: resolutions,                        
                tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(layerInfo.tileInfo.cols, layerInfo.tileInfo.rows),                        
                tileOrigin: new OpenLayers.LonLat(layerInfo.tileInfo.origin.x , layerInfo.tileInfo.origin.y),                        
                maxExtent: layerMaxExtent,                        
                projection: 'EPSG:' + layerInfo.spatialReference.wkid
            });

    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest("ArcGIS Server Layer",
    "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/USA_Median_Home_Value/MapServer/export?transparent=true&", 
            {layers: "show:0,1,2,3,4", FORMAT:"png24", srs:3857},{singleTile: true});

    //add the 2 layers
    map.addLayers([cacheLayer, layer]);

    map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition() );

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-120, 45).transform(geographic, mercator), 4);

    layer.setVisibility(true); //set visibility
}

function moveEvent(event){
    layer.redraw(true); //force refresh
}
```

A working JS fiddle is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/devdatta/rDfUx/3/